# get hold of the relationship id array of a node

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

I need a fast way to measure the number of relationships on a particular Neo4J node.
this information is (i believe) available on NodeImpl.getRelationshipIds()

My problem is that in my application i have an instance of a NodeProxy
that is returned to me from an index hit

is there a way i can grab an instance of the NodeImpl by a given ID?
(my intention is then to cast it on one of my own classes that extends it and get the info i am looking for)

the other option is of course to iterate on the results from the proxy, but that is a huge strain on performance.

cheers
gilad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getRelationshipIds()` will also have to load and iterate over those relationships.

If you don't access anything from the relationships it will be similarly fast.

Did you try/measure to just iterate over the relationships and only access `rel.getId()`

Is this the first load (i.e. cold caches, loading from disk) or subsequent ones?

Otherwise you might also want to look into something like graphaware:

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-relcount